# update method of ActiveRecord failed because UNIQUE constraint failed: items.id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In this case,

```
product = <Item id: 4, url: nil, memo: nil, created_at: "2015-11-07 09:48:36", updated_at: "2015-11-07 09:48:36", Totalweight: 390.0, Perweight: nil, price: 1000>
attr = {"id"=>4, "tag_list"=>"peanuts", "price"=>1000, "url"=>nil, "Totalweight"=>390, "memo"=>nil}
```

I did to update Item's a record.

```
product.update!(attr)
```

but error said,

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException　UNIQUE constraint failed: items.id
!! #<ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: items.id: INSERT INTO "items" ("id", "price", "Totalweight", "created_at", "updated_at", "url") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)>
```

Of course id is same because I want to update the record.
i tried

```
product.update_attributes(attr)
```

also shows same error.

**Question is How can I update this Item object?**

ActiveRecord's save method is working if id is not set.

in addition, more information,
Im using gem 'roo' that import Excel, CSV files and can parse.
https://github.com/roo-rb/roo
argument row is from gem 'roo'

here is the code,

```
  COLUMN = ["id","tag_list","price","url","Perweight","Totalweight", "memo", "id", "created_at", "updated_at"]

  def self.import(file)
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      if Item.find(row["id"]) then
        product = Item.new
        attr = row.slice(*COLUMN)
        # product.attributes = attr
        product.update(attr)
      else
        product = Item.new
        attr = row.slice(*COLUMN)
        product.attributes = attr
        product.save!
      end
    end
  end

  def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
    when ".csv" then
      Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path, extension: :csv)
    when ".xls" then
      Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path, extension: :xls)
    when ".xlsx" then
      Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path, extension: :xlsx)
    else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already checking whether an Item exists or not - that is good.
But you're not upgrading the existing Item, you're creating a new one even if one with the same ID already exists, and that's why you get the error.

There are two ways to solve this - the first one is a bit more verbose, but closer to what you already have:

```
product = Item.find(row["id"])
if product then
  attr = row.slice(*COLUMN)
  # Update the existing product
  product.update(attr)
else
...
end
```

However, since you do the same thing to the product object anyway, regardless of whether it exists or not, you can also do this:

```
# This will either find an existing product, or initialize a new one with the ID
product = Item.find_or_initialize_by(id: row["id"])
attr = row.slice(*COLUMN)
product.attributes = attr
product.save!
```

Comment: Thank you Mr Nils!! I spent 6 hours to solve this problem!!

Comment: I didnt need to create two same id instance!! I didnt know that!